# Why is the following dataset giving me a negative R squared value?

Tags: scikit-learn, r-squared

This is my code, I calculated R square using Scikit learn :

```
y =[0, 10, 20, 30, 40]
f =[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
r2 = r2_score(y, f)
print('r2 score for perfect model is', r2)
```

Output :

```
r2 score for perfect model is -1.4300000000000002
```

Why is this coming out negative?

Comment: FAQ: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=negative+r+square.

Comment: In order to point you to the specific parts of the duplicate that are pertinent to your particular confusion, why do you think the $R^2$ returned by your code should be $1?$ (You refer to a perfect model, so I assume you expect a perfect $R^2$.)

Comment: Yes, it's a perfect fit, so why am i getting a negative value?

Comment: How is it a perfect fit? Your observed value is 40, and you predict 4 (or maybe you observed 4 and predicted 40). // You might be interested in my simulations [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/584562/247274) and the paragraph right below the simulation code.