# MSPE and $R^2_{OOS}$

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, r-squared, mse, out-of-sample

I've been looking at a paper for a while that I find interesting. It's essentially a comparative analysis where the authors are comparing PCA/PLS to different machine learning methods. The aim is to predict bond risk premia so they report MSPE and R^2_{OOS} as their main results. But the results are a bit puzzling to me. You see, they report these values for bond maturities 2,3,4 and 5 and both performance measures rise as the maturities do. Isn't this contradictory since a MSPE value is better the closer to 0 it is and R^2_{OOS} is better the higher it gets? Or is there something that I'm missing?

Thanks for reading.

(I've have attached the table of results)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFgZm.png

Edit: At the request of a comment: A bond is essentially a loan and the maturity is the remaining lenght of the loan. So if a bond has a maturity of (for instance) 2, there are two years until the bond expires and the principal has to be repaid.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Many statisticians are interested in finance, but this is not a community where it should be expected that everyone knows what bond maturities $2$ through $5$ mean. Could you please clarify in an edit to the original question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two components influence the out-of-sample $R^2$, and only one is the MSPE (mean squared prediction error). As the bond maturities change, yes, the MSPE increases, and if the $R^2$ denominators were the same, then the $R^2$ values would decrease. However, the denominator values need not stay the same.

$$
R^2_{oos}=1-\dfrac{
MSPE_{model}
}{
MSPE_{baseline}
}
$$

If the numerator increases but the denominator also increases, then there could be an increase in our-of-sample $R^2$.

As an aside, looking at the linked table, watch about for those $R^2$ values below zero, which indicate terrible performance worse than a simple baseline like predicting the historical mean (likely how the denominator is calculated).

**EDIT**

Another possibility, though it turns out not to apply here, is that the paper calculates $R^2_{oos}$ by squaring the Pearson correlation between the true and predicted values, which loses the relationship with MSPE, discussed in my answer [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/114457/73930) and demonstrated graphically in my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/584562/247274). That the paper reports values below zero, however, rules out such a calculation of $R^2_{oos}$.